# Streaming audio in windows phone 7 browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, browser, stream, mms

I need some help streaming audio inside the browser, on a Nokia Lumia 800, running Windows Mobile 7.5.

I currently am using JW Player (flash version) on the desktop browser, to stream an rtmp:// audio provided to me, and that works great. I also have an mms:// version of the same audio stream provided, but I cannot get it to play in the browser on the phone. I have tried setting the mode for JW Player to html5, but it doesn't work.
All the documentation on streaming audio on the windows phone seems to deal with native app development, but that's not an option for this at the moment.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but neither the RTMP or MMS protocols are supported in HTML5 or Windows Phone (all versions), either natively or in the browser. You won't find support for either of these protocols even with a native app in WP7.x. WP8 opens up the possibilty of this functionality in 3rd party apps.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it wasn't even possible natively in 7.5. That's crazy. Oh well, back to the drawing board for this idea then. Thanks for the answer.